# input 3 digit number and print the highest number

Tags: java

How to determine the highest number in 3 digit number?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{

public static void main(final String args[]) {

    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a, b, c;
    final int num = in.nextInt();

    a = num / 100;
    b = (num / 10) % 10;
    c = num % 10;

    if (a > b) {
      if (a > c) {
        System.out.println(a);
      } else {
        System.out.println(c);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

> *input: 173*
> *expected output: 7*
>
> *input: 109*
> *expected output: 9*

Comment: There being no `System.out.println(b);` is a red flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**simple way...**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
 public static void main(final String args[]) {

 final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

 int a, b, c;
 System.out.print("Enter 3 digit number :");
 int num = in.nextInt();

 a = num / 100;
 b = (num / 10) % 10;
 c = num % 10;

 if (a > b && a > c) {
  System.out.print("Largest number is:"+a);
 } else if(b > c) {
  System.out.print("Largest number is:"+b);
  } else {
   System.out.print("Largest number is:"+c);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You idea of using the modulus here is a good one:

```java
int input = in.nextInt();
int num = Math.abs(num);
int highestDigit = -1;

while (num > 0) {
    int digit = num % 10;
    if (digit > highestDigit) {
        highestDigit = digit;
    }
    num /= 10;
}

System.out.println("Highest digit in " + input + " is: " + highestDigit);
```

The above solution iterate over the number input by checking the final digit, and keeping track of the highest digit seen.  Note that in each iteration of the loop, we divide the input by 10, after inspecting that final digit.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing condition in case when `a < b`. That also need to be added as below :

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {

    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a, b, c;
    System.out.println("Please enter 3 digit number. Ex : 197, 187, 981 etc.");
    final int num = in.nextInt();

    a = num / 100;
    b = (num / 10) % 10;
    c = num % 10;

    if (a > b) {
      if (a > c) {
        System.out.println(a);
      } else {
        System.out.println(c);
      }
    } else {
      if (b > c) {
        System.out.println(b);
      } else {
        System.out.println(c);
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also get the input to string and then change it to integer and check each value:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String digits = input.next();
        input.close();
        
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
            if(Character.getNumericValue(digits.charAt(i)) > max) {
                max = Character.getNumericValue(digits.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{

public static void main(final String args[]) {

```
final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int a, b, c;
final int num = in.nextInt();

a = num / 100;
b = (num / 10) % 10;
c = num % 10;

if (a > b) {
     if (a > c)
    System.out.println(a);
         }
           

 if(b > a){
    if(b > c)
    System.out.println(b);
         }


         if(c > a){
            if(c > b)
         System.out.println(b);
                  }
```

}
}